# __add not working in custom Vector3 class

Tags: lua, metatable

I am making a custom Vector3 class for a 3D engine I am making. I am kinda new to lua and not at the stage I should be making a 3D engine, but who cares.
My Vector3 script looks like this.

```
#Vector3.lua
function Vector3(x,y,z) end

Vector3 = 
{
  __add = function(a,b)
    return Vector3(
      a.x + b.x,
      a.y + b.y,
      a.z + b.z
    )
  end
}
Vector3.__index = Vector3

function Vector3.new(x,y,z)
  local instance = 
  {
    x = x or 0,
    y = y or 0,
    z = z or 0
  }
  setmetatable(instance, Vector3)
  return instance
end

function Vector3:printX()
  return self.x
end
```

and my main like this:

```
#main.lua
require "Vector3"

vec1 = Vector3.new(1,2,3)
vec2 = Vector3.new(5,1,0)
vec3 = vec1 + vec2

print(vec3.x)
```

But it gives an error when I run it:

```
attempt to index global 'Vector3' (a function value)
stack traceback
```

I did this trying to have the __add function able to add two Vector3 classes. I know I am doing it incorrectly and I can't find a solution. How would I add the __add function to my script?
This is the original Vector3.lua:

```
#Vector3.lua
Vector3 = {}
Vector3.__index = Vector3

function Vector3.new(x,y,z)
  local instance = 
  {
    x = x or 0,
    y = y or 0,
    z = z or 0
  }
  setmetatable(instance, Vector3)
  return instance
end

function Vector3:printX()
  return self.x
end
```

Comment: In `__add`, use `return Vector3.new(`.

Comment: @lhf Thank you. that worked. If you could explain why that works even though I define the Vector3.new() function after, that would be great.

Comment: The value will be retrieved at the time the `__add` is called after it gets modified. You could technically avoid it by prepending `local` to both `Vector3` declarations (table definition will shadow function definition in the later code), but don't do that. Check [cpml's vec3](https://github.com/excessive/cpml/blob/master/modules/vec3.lua) how to do it differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first definition of `Vector3` that you have at the top of *Vector3.lua* is overwritten immediately:

```lua
function Vector3(x,y,z) end

Vector3 = 
{
-- ...
}
```

Global `Vector3` is now a table and not a function. Later on in `__add` you try to call constructor via simplified `Vector3()`:

```lua
__add = function(a, b)
  return Vector3(
--       ^^^^^^^^ here
    a.x + b.x,
    a.y + b.y,
    a.z + b.z
  )
end
```

Update that call to `Vector3.new(...)` or implement `__call` metamethod to construct the object (see [2.3 - Metatables and Metamethods](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4)). The error message suggests that there is another mix-up but if you clean up the code and implement one of the previous options it should be resolved.

Comment: Sigh, I guess I need to refresh page more often and check comments while writing the answer...

Comment: Thanks for the answer though. I needed one to mark as correct